# Colour indication in the R plot

Tags: r

Trying to add some note at the bottom of R plot graph, to show what colour and line type has been used in the graph that represents for. Tried use mtext() function, but that only allow me to add text, not the line type. Any way to add those colour note?
[image]

Comment: Hi Jason. Is this a base R plot? Is the image one you have produced, or is this what you are trying to produce? Perhaps a little sample of your plotting data and code would allow others to help you?

Comment: HI it is just base R plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. Please next time follow the advice of @AllanCameron. There are plenty of people wanting to help you, but we need to analyse your data to discover the issue. Here I have used some dummy data similar to that showed in the plot. Next an approach for your issue. If you want a description of your data series you can add a legend. This can be done also using `ggplot2` which is used in actual code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Year=2000:2009,
                 Positive=runif(10,0,1),
                 Negative=runif(10,-1,0),
                 Average=cumsum(seq(-0.5,1,length.out = 10)))
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(Year),y=Positive))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Average,group=1,color='Average'),size=1)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black',aes(fill='Positive'),show.legend = T)+
  geom_bar(aes(y=Negative,fill='Negative'),stat='identity',color='black')+
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c('red','blue','white'))+
  scale_color_manual("",values = 'black')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',legend.key.height = unit(0.001,'mm'))+
  xlab('Year')+labs(caption = 'Your Info')
```

Output:

[image]

You can play around key size to make it thinner.